# Wrap a list to add an empty row for UI binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am binding a List to a UI Control.  My list does not contain a blank row, but I need to add one to allow the user to select blank.  However, I'm using the same list in other parts of the application (users can edit/add/delete items) where it doesn't make sense to show a blank row.

My idea is to create a wrapper around the list which adds a blank row just for the UI.  The wrapper would hold a reference so that updates to the list (from other parts of the app) would be reflected in UI without any extra work.

I have tried a few different ways, but nothing has worked out for me yet.  Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us why you think you need the empty row -- it may be the case that you just want to implement [`IBindingList.AddNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.addnew.aspx)

Comment: I need the empty row so users can pick a 'nothing' value.  For example, I could have a combobox filled with months, but user is not required to choose a value so they can set it to blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found an answer to this.  My solution was to make a copy of my list and add a 'blank' row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a Forms.DataGridView, you may use

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

or let the user deselect rows by holding *strg* and clicking the selected row (this is standard behavior of the DataGridView)

Then ask for

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0
```

to figure, whether no row is selected, which i would interpret as blank ;)